# How can you create a new (xml) file in angular testing

Tags: angular, blob, angular2-testing

I am working on an unittest in a Angular(2) project.
But I ran into an issue that I can not create a new File for my test.

In my test I have the following code:

```
const newfile = new Blob(['ANEWFILE001'], {
    type: 'application/xml',
    endings: 'native'
});

data = [
    {
        file: {
            file: new File(newfile, "FILENAME001.xml",)
        } as FileLoadBar
    }
];
```

file: new File(**newfile**, "FILENAME001.xml",)
newfile results in the following error:
*Argument of type 'Blob' is not assignable to parameter of type '(string | ArrayBuffer | Blob | ArrayBufferView)[]'.

Property 'find' is missing in type 'Blob'.*
How do I create a new File in an angular unitetest.

If there is any information needed for solving this issue please let me know.

Comment: Adding parenthesis is not the solution (blob has no compatible call signature error will occur)

Answer (score 0):

I missed the brackets.

file: new File(**[newfile]**, "FILENAME001.xml",)